# Serialization and Deserialization of XML Document using threads

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, serialization

Normally I do XML Serialization using an entire method that goes somewhat like this

```
        XmlSerializer seralizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Method));
        StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter TextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(strWriter);
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        seralizer.Serialize(TextWriter, Method_Name, ns);
```

And Deserialization that comes after that goes something like this

```
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Method_Name), XmlRoot);

        XmlNodeReader Reader = new XmlNodeReader(XmlStringDoc.DocumentElement);

        objUpdateHotelAllotment = (Method_Name)Serializer.Deserialize(Reader);
```

**Is there any way that these two processes can be carried out using threads, so that when deserialization is being carried out for the first XML, serialization can begin on the second XML ?** Use the above codes in thread to illustrate; it's much appreciated.

Comment: Using threads doesn't improve anything just by it being encapsulated inside a thread.

Comment: I know for a fact that using BinaryFormatting is not thread safe and IMHO I wouldn't use it as of yet, that's the reason I thought threads might lead to a new door

Comment: Your questions looks like the [*xy problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you can elaborate more on the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread safety is no issue if each thread gets its own `new XmlSerializer()`. So yes, you can just do that.

Comment: Can you provide me with sample code to illustrate this ? When deserialization is being carried out for the first XML, serialization should begin on the second XML

Comment: Stick the code in a method and call `new Thread(YourMethod).Start()`.